# Can I delete .msp files?

Tags: filesystems, disk-space

I have a load of .msp files that i would like to delete, will this harm my system at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google yielded the following File Extensions Resource page for [.msp](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/msp). However, a little more digging suggests [you shouldn't delete .msp files](http://www.ava.co.uk/support/faq/general/what-are-msp-files.aspx).

My maxim for this sort of thing is: If you're unsure, don't do it. If you're brave (and understand the potential consequences), rename it and reboot!

Answer (score 5):

.msp files can be a couple of things but these are probably Microsoft update files.  In general **you should never delete anything inside the Windows directory unless you know what you're doing**.

It's good that you asked first, because **if you have to ask, or you don't know what the files are for, you delete them at your own risk**.

Comment: Can I fix that for you? "You should never delete anything inside the Windows directory, period."

Comment: @Randolph - Hey, I had to purge a corrupted print spooler cache the other day. ;)  But yeah, let me update the answer to be a little clearer.

Comment: I've voted you up.

Comment: @Randolph - And just let me go on the record as stating that I do agree with you as advice for standard users.  Unfortunately, I'm just too pedantic to state it across the board. :)

Comment: You can often try moving the file to another directory or renaming it before actually deleting to see if it's something important. Creating a backup just-in-case is another good defensive tactic when changing things you're unsure about doing (like deleting files).